# How do I select an entire row in Excel?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2010

How do I highlight all cells in an Excel row?

I'm using Excel 2010 on Windows.

Comment: I tightened up the question. As it where it had 3 close votes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The shortcut to select a complete row is <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.

Similarly, the shortcut to select a complete column, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.

You can also select the whole row by clicking on the row header. This works for column headers too.

Comment: I just want to ctrl-a one row of data from a column so I can ctrl-c

Comment: @Shades what do you mean by just one row of data with `Ctrl+A`? If I understand you correctly then you want to use this shortcut for this particular task then you need AutoHotKey (I think?).

Comment: Well, I'm sorry, in your case I'd be happy that Microsoft was so consistent as to make `Ctrl-A` select *everything* and not just a row :P @Shades

Comment: I have 3 columns: Firstname, lastname, id. I need to copy out each individuals lastname only and paste into a separate file. So I just wanted to know if i could ctrl a and ctrl c individuals rows from "Fx" box instead of having to click and drag to highlight and then hit ctrl c from the Fx box

Comment: @Shades Have you thought about using `Ctrl-Space` to select the entire column, then copy it with `Ctrl-C`? I mean, that's what I already wrote in the answer, but …

Comment: Yes I tried it. It's ok. I'll just keep doing what I was doing before. It's not a big deal. Just simply wanted to know if there was a way. I'm very much a beginner with Excel. Thanks

Comment: In won't be possible to select only one row if it is part of a group. The whole group will be selected. Maybe there is a workaround in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Similarly, to select only the contiguous cells with data in them, i.e. not every cell on the current sheet...

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> will select the row

and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>down arrow</kbd> will select the column

Incidentally, choose up, down, left, or right depending on where you are on the sheet.  The keyboard combinations above will select in the direction you hit *from* the selected cell as the starting point.